# React prop shows as empty on first load after change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I have an application which follows these steps:

- User adds a new currency to account
- HTTP request sent to server
- Then `this.props.refreshSession` updates the props
- Then redirect to a page which requires the currency selection to be present in props.

I'm thinking the issue might be related to the last step. Maybe my `then` function is triggering early? I've added `return Promise.resolve()` inside my `refreshSession` action to allow it to be chained with `then` and redirect only after it has been completed.

**Step #1 code adding a currency:**

```
fetch(appConfig.apiUri + "/currency", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': authHeader,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(userJSON)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
  this.props.refreshSession().then(
    () => this.setState({redirect: true})
  )
})
```

**Step #2 code `this.props.refreshSession`:**

```
export function refreshSession () {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return cognitoUtils.getCognitoSession()
        .then((session) => {
        axios.post(appConfig.apiUri + "/users", session.user,
        { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${session.credentials.accessToken}`} })
          .then(res => {
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              console.log("User data updated");
              session.userData = res.data.user;
              dispatch({ type: SET_SESSION, session })
              return Promise.resolve();
            });
          });
      })
  }
}
```

**Step #3**

```
if(this.props.session.userData) {
  if(this.props.session.userData.claimed) {
    claimedType = this.props.session.userData.claimed[getUrlParameter('type').toUpperCase()];
    // above line breaks, with error that amount is undefined
```

Yet if I look in the Redux dev tool extension I can see that the data I'm trying to use in the prop seems to be present.

[image]

If I refresh the page it immediately works.

I'm sorry for the somewhat unclear question but I've been stuck on this for a while now and I'm having trouble figuring out why the props haven't been updated on the first load.

*Update: I guess I would want to return the promise resolve after `dispatch({ type: SET_SESSION, session })` finishes instead of at the same time as it. I'm still not sure how to implement it.*

**Code for Reducer:**

```
const session = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SESSION:
      return Object.assign({},
        action.session,
        { isLoggedIn: true })

    case CLEAR_SESSION:
      return initialState

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add reducer code as well?

Comment: @OzanBulut added reducer code at bottom

Comment: Adding code of reducer makes your question clearly but  as my assumption, it's just React behavior, either you put your code for fetching data in `componentDidMount` (class component) or `useEffect` (functional component), both of them run after the inital render.

Comment: @dqlgnoleht I'm using `react-router` the fetch takes place on one page and it is loaded on a second which I want to load only after the action is complete (this happens when `redirect` is set to true in the state). As the data is in the props I don't think fetching it in the `componentDidMount` of the second page would help. I think there might be a way to do what I want using `redux-thunk`.

Comment: So your case is the data was loaded in page A then the store update then redirecting to page B and on the first load of page B, the data in props are not available ?